# How can I make React Component Structure in Idea Intellij 15?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I'm new to IntelliJ Idea and working with IntelliJ Idea 15. I'm working on a react project. I want something which can generate a react component by the direct click in that folder. e.g.

[image]

Now there should be an option for making a new React Component. Upon clicking that a pop-up should open which should ask what files I want to add in the Component's Directory. e.g. the structure should be :

e.g.

- Component

  - Component.js
  - index.js
  - component.scss
  - test Directory

    - Component.test.js

These should be configured according to the need of user. I don't know java and anything about IntelliJ plugins development. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the template settings:

Windows and Linux: **File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates**
macOS: **IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates**

Click on the plus button and add a new template:

Name: `React Component`
Extension: `js`

This template works well for me:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
class ${NAME} extends Component {
  render() {
    const { } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

${NAME}.propTypes = {

};

export default ${NAME};
```

You can also [PureComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) or add some default props if you like.

Comment: Hi, I want to add the folder structure I mentioned in the question. It should make a directory by default

Comment: I do not think that is possible.. I think this is best Intellij can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that you need such a structure of the component. React components are pretty much straight forward. You just create a JavaScript file and write like that.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class YourComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <h1>Hello React</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default YourComponent;
```